# Пустые места в канве

Tags: html, html5, canvas

Здравствуйте. Работаю над скриптом несколько часов, и если честно, рационально мыслить уже не способен.

Откуда ни возьмись начали появляться пустые места. Кто знает, в чём проблема?

```js
var game = {
  canvas: null,
  ctx: null,
  centerX: null,
  centerY: null,

  init: function() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    this.centerX = this.canvas.width / 2;
    this.centerY = this.canvas.height / 2;

    this.circle.init();
  },

  circle: {
    params: {
      R: 100,

      user_stroke_width: 25,

      anim_speed: 500
    },

    colors: [
      "red",
      "blue",
      "green",
      "yellow"
    ],

    clear: function() {
      var ctx = game.ctx;

      ctx.save();

      ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, game.canvas.width, game.canvas.height);

      ctx.restore();
    },

    init: function() {
      var
        ctx = game.ctx;
      endingAngle = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < game.bets.users.length; i++) {
        var bets_user = game.bets.users[i];

        if (i > 0 && !game.bets.users[i - 1].finished) {
          continue;
        }

        if (bets_user.angle.start < bets_user.angle.max) {
          ctx.beginPath();

          startingAngle = bets_user.angle.start * Math.PI;
          endingAngle = (bets_user.angle.start + this.params.set) * Math.PI;

          if (endingAngle / Math.PI > 2) {
            endingAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
          }

          ctx.arc(game.centerX, game.centerY, this.params.R, startingAngle, endingAngle, false);

          ctx.lineWidth = this.params.user_stroke_width;
          ctx.strokeStyle = this.colors[i];
          ctx.stroke();

          bets_user.angle.start += this.params.set;
        } else {
          bets_user.finished = true;
        }
      }

      if (!bets_user.finished) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          game.circle.init();
        }, 1);
      }
    }
  },

  bets: {
    all: 0,

    users: [{
      size: 20
    }, {
      size: 24
    }, {
      size: 134
    }, {
      size: 34
    }],

    set_all: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
        this.all += this.users[i].size;
      }

      game.circle.params.set = 2 / game.circle.params.anim_speed * 4;
    },

    config: function() {
      this.set_all();

      for (var i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
        var portion = 100 / this.all * this.users[i].size;

        this.users[i].radians = portion / 100 * 2;

        var start_angle = i == 0 ? 0 : this.users[i - 1].angle.max;

        this.users[i].angle = {
          start: start_angle,
          max: start_angle + this.users[i].radians
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  game.bets.config();
  game.init();
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="225" height="225"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в `lineCap`. Как я понимаю, значение по умолчанию `butt` создает секции, по размеру недостаточные для перекрытия друг друга, образуя зазоры. К сожалению, используя варианты с `round` и `square` не удается получить приемлемый результат.